# HTTP requests in Meteor package?

Tags: node.js, http, meteor, http-headers, html-parsing

I'm trying to pull the meta info form a some web page using http meteor packet, to pull this info.
How to retrieve the meta keyword and description in a web page using HTTP meteor package?

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
HTTP.call('GET', 'http://example.com', function(err, res){
   if(res.statusCode === 200 && res.content){
      var metaKeywords = /name="keywords" content="(.*)"/gim.exec(res.content)[1];
      var metaDescription = /name="description" content="(.*)"/gim.exec(res.content)[1];
   }
});
```

You may need to play with Regular Expression.

Comment: @juan-carlos-sanchez-mejia please accept, or give a comment if this solution not solved your issue